# When exactly do React Hook states get set?

Tags: reactjs, rendering, state, react-hooks, rerender

I am trying to understand the order of execution for the following piece of code involving React Hook states:

```
const App = () => {
  const [ searchedCountry, setSearchedCountry ] = useState(''); 
  const [ filteredArr, setFilteredArr ]  = useState([]); 
  const [ filteredLength, setFilteredLength ] = useState(0);

  //...

  const filterCountries = (event) => { 
    event.preventDefault();

    setFilteredArr(countries.filter(country => country.name.includes(searchedCountry)));  
    setFilteredLength(filteredArr.length); 
    console.log("filtered arr length", filtered.length);
  }

  //...
}
```

When `filterCountries` is triggered, `setFilteredArr` sets the state, `filteredArr`, to an array filtered by a query. However, when exactly does `filteredArr` get set?

`filteredArr.length` returns `0`, meaning `filteredArr` has not been set yet, even after calling `setFilteredArr`.

At first, I thought by executing `setFilteredArr`, the component re-renders, causing execution to skip the method calls after `setFilteredArr`. That would explain why `filteredArr.length` is `0`. However, the `console.log` is still called, meaning after a component re-renders, the order of execution is actually resumed.

What is going on? When exactly does `filteredArr` get set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to remember is: all your state variables are local variables. They only exist for this particular time the component rendered. So on the first render, `console.log("filtered arr length", filteredArr.length);` is referring to the array that exists on that first render. `filteredArr` will never be assigned a new array (it can't, it's a const), and unless you mutate the array (which you shouldn't), the length of that array will always be 0.

When you call setFilteredArr, this instructs react to rerender the component. React might do the rendering synchronously, or it might wait to try to batch up changes. When that 2nd render happens, you make a call to useState and get back the new value. This is assigned to a local variable named filteredArr, but this is a completely different variable than the one we had on the first render. The console.log statement in that first render, will have no way to access the variable in the second render. But the second render has access to it, so any logging you do the second time will show the second array.

Comment: Are you saying that a state is set as soon as the state modifying function is called, but at the current render, the new state is not accessible until the next render? I am still having a hard time following the order of execution.

Comment: I'm saying the order of execution is a red herring. Each time the component renders, it creates a brand new set of local variables. There's a new `filteredArr` variable, and a new `filteredCountries` function. That function "closes over" the filteredArr variable from this render. In other words, code in the filteredCountries function only has access to variables that exist on this particular rendering. It cannot access variables that will be created the next time the component renders.

Answer (score 0):

setState or 'setFilteredLength' is an async operation. After you call it, it will take some time to update the state (as it is async, it will not wait for that update. It will simply execute the next line) so when it executes the console.log the value has not changed -> yet